# Can Anyone help me retrieve data from parse using unity please?

Tags: c#, parse-platform, unity-game-engine

I have managed to store data, but I can't retrieve it and i would be so grateful if someone could just help me get at least 1 example working.

First I am storing data when the user signs up:

```
public void SetupNewParseMember(ParseUser user)
{
    ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
    gameScore["cash"] = 500;
    gameScore["playerName"] = user.Username;
    gameScore["HighestCash"] = 500;
    gameScore["GamesPlayed"] = 0;


    Task saveTask = gameScore.SaveAsync();

}
```

This works fine, I can see the data in parse and all seems ok..

The problem is when i try to retrieve the objects.

```
public void SetupMainScreen(ParseUser user)
{
    var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("GameScore").WhereEqualTo("playerName", user.Username);
    query.FindAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = t.Result;

        List<ParseObject> resultsList = results.ToList();

        DealWithResults(resultsList, user);

    });
}

public void DealWithResults(List<ParseObject> resultsList, ParseUser me)
{

    userGamesPlayed = resultsList[1].Get<int>("GamesPlayed");
    userHighestCash = resultsList[2].Get<int>("HighestCash");
    userCash = resultsList[3].Get<int>("Cash");

    WelcomeText.text = "Welcome, " + me.Username + "\n" +
                   "Cash: $" + userCash + "\n" +
                   "Highest Cash: $" + userHighestCash + "\n" +
                   "Games Played: " + userGamesPlayed;
}
```

First I tried just making changes to the unity ui from inside the Query but that did not work, So i made an outside function and passed the results to it that way, and that still does not work?

I tried to debug what i was getting in the list with this:

```
foreach (var res in resultsList)
        {
            Debug.Log("Class Name = " + res.ClassName + "| Keys are: " + res.Keys);
        }
```

But all it returned was:

```
Class Name = GameScore| Keys are: System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection[System.String,System.Object]
```

Can anyone offer any insights?

EDIT2:

ok so first i found results list and its contents
https://i.stack.imgur.com/me54A.png

Then if i open it, it seems to be null ref?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpsKa.png

But if i go digging, i found the info i need all the way down here
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXQUr.png

Now just need to work out how to get it?

Comment: If you break in `DealWithResults` what are the contents of `resultList`?

Comment: How do you add breaks in unity?

Comment: I don't know Unity, but isn't there an IDE where you can run your code in debug mode? Like this perhaps - http://docs.unity3d.com/432/Documentation/Manual/Debugger.html

Comment: ok got it working with VS.. sorry for delay. That is so awesome..

ok so first i found results list and its contents
http://i.imgur.com/IKcBbey.png


Then if i open it, it seems to be null ref?

http://i.imgur.com/VmSpi9c.png

But if i go digging, i found the info i need all the way down here
http://i.imgur.com/1Wwu5uc.png

Now just need to work out how to get it? What do you think?

Comment: If it helps, parse gives this example.http://hastebin.com/toweferuco.avrasm

however i do not know how to get the information out of the ienumerable ParseObject.

Answer (score 1):

As there is only one set of data it is always accessible through `resultsList[0]`. What you want is:

```
double cash = (double)resultsList[0]["cash"];
string playerName = (string)resultsList[0]["playerName"];
double highestCash = (double)resultsList[0]["HighestCash"];
int gamesPlayed = (int)resultsList[0]["GamesPlayed"];
```

Though you probably want to check that `resultsList` is not null and contains one element before you try to dereference it.

Also as your `ParseObject` appears to be a `Dictionary` you might find [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) useful.

Comment: I get errors trying to cast to the types... I can use var cash, but then it makes it an object?

would this work?

var cash = resultsList[0].Get<int>("cash");

Comment: @MIke - yeah. Sorry. You need to cast.

Comment: Now i get erros from accessing unity outside the main thread :( its like u cant acccess variables inside the query... but how do i get them out

This is the error, get_isActiveAndEnabled can only be called from the main thread.
Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene.
Don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, instead move initialization code to the Awake or Start function.

Comment: but we worked out it only happens when i try to change the unity ui inside queries...no idea why

Comment: You need to look into how threading works and passing data between threads.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving it.. Much different to the examples...

I had to make a coroutine that called a function on callback to access the variables outside of the query.

I called it with

```
StartCoroutine(SetupMainScreen(me, DealWithResults));
```

then called this.

```
public IEnumerator SetupMainScreen(ParseUser user, Action<GameScore> callback)
{



    var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("GameScore").WhereEqualTo("playerName", user.Username).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    while (!query.IsCompleted)
    {
        yield return null;
    }

    if (query.IsFaulted || query.IsCanceled)
    {
        Debug.Log("Getting of GameScores faulted or cancelled...");
    }
    else
    {
        var obj = query.Result;
        if (obj != null)
            callback(new GameScore(obj.Get<int>("cash"),obj.Get<string>("playerName"),obj.Get<int>("HighestCash"),obj.Get<int>("GamesPlayed")));
    }


}

public void DealWithResults(GameScore gs)
{

    WelcomeText.text = "Welcome, " + gs.Username + "\n" +
                   "Cash: $" + gs.Cash + "\n" +
                   "Highest Cash: $" + gs.HighestCash + "\n" +
                   "Games Played: " + gs.GamesPlayed;
}
```

And i just made a class to hold the objects.. Hopefully this helps someone else.